# Set ASP.NET autocomplete extender contextKey dynamically in code behind

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I want to use ASP.NET autocomplete in my page. I use my internal object for loading data and autocomplete should be queried with parameteres which are instance page field values. Because I can't use instance fields in static autocomplete extender method, I've found a [sample of code](http://mscoder.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dynamically-set-the-autocompleteextender-contextkey/), which can be used to achieve my goal.

I have textbox and autocomplete extender in asp.net page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBox" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
                            SkinID="SalesReturnTextBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" 
                            AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBoxTextChanged" 
                            onload="PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBoxLoad" />
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBox" ID="OrderOrStockNumberExtender"
                            ServiceMethod="GetOrderOrStockNumbers" MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="1000" UseContextKey="True"/>
```

In PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBoxLoad method I want to set context key dynamically via javascript according to example noticed above.

```
protected void PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBoxLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox!=null)
        {                
            string sapCode = Customer.Company.SapCode;
            const string PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION = PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION_HP;
            string purchaseGroup = string.Empty;
            string firstDateTime = FirstDateTextBox.Text;
            const string SEPARATOR = "#";
            var contextStrings = new[]{sapCode,PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION,purchaseGroup,firstDateTime};
            string context =string.Join(SEPARATOR, contextStrings);
            const string ON_KEY_UP = "onkeyup";
            string attributevalue = "$find('" + OrderOrStockNumberExtender.ClientID + "').set_contextKey(" + context +
                                    ");";
            textBox.Attributes.Add(ON_KEY_UP, attributevalue);
        }
    }
```

But when I run my page and set breakpoint in static web method which should return string array, I find that contextKey is null.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string[] GetOrderOrStockNumbers(string prefixText,int count, string contextKey)
{            
    string[] returnStrings = new string[] {"1","2"};
    return returnStrings;
}
```

Thank you very much for any helpful answer,

Rudolf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. ContextKey set by attribute value couldn't work in ASP.NET, because .Net 4.0 escape apostrophes in attribute values as I found in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1554455.aspx/) article.

One solution is to disable encoding attribute values in web config, but it could create a security problem.

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="HtmlAttributeEncodingNot"/>
```

I've rather changed my approach and didn't set contextKey value by attribute, but registered client script in prerender event of textbox control.

```
protected void PurchaseOrderItemsSearchTextBoxPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            string sapCode = Customer.Company.SapCode;
            const string PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION = PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION_HP;
            string purchaseGroup = string.Empty;
            string firstDateTime = FirstDateTextBox.Text;
            var contextStrings = new[] {sapCode, PURCHASE_ORGANIZATION, purchaseGroup, firstDateTime};
            string context = string.Join(SEPARATOR, contextStrings);
            const string ON_KEY_UP = "onkeyup";
            const string ON_KEY_UP_VALUE = "SetOrderOrStockExtenderContextKey();";
            textBox.Attributes.Add(ON_KEY_UP, ON_KEY_UP_VALUE);

            //disable autocomplete in firefox
            DisableAutocompleteInFirefox(textBox);

            const string ORDER_OR_STOCK_NUMBER_SCRIPT_KEY = "OrderOrStockNumberScript";
            if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(ORDER_OR_STOCK_NUMBER_SCRIPT_KEY))
            {
                Type type = GetType();
                var scriptTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                const string FUNCTION_NAME = "function SetOrderOrStockExtenderContextKey()";
                scriptTextBuilder.AppendLine(FUNCTION_NAME);
                const string LEFT_BRACKET = "{";
                scriptTextBuilder.AppendLine(LEFT_BRACKET);
                const string FIND_COMMAND = "$find(\'";
                scriptTextBuilder.Append(FIND_COMMAND);
                scriptTextBuilder.Append(OrderOrStockNumberExtender.ClientID);
                const string SET_COTEXT_KEY = "\').set_contextKey('";
                scriptTextBuilder.Append(SET_COTEXT_KEY);
                scriptTextBuilder.Append(context);
                const string END_OF_COMMAND = "');";
                scriptTextBuilder.AppendLine(END_OF_COMMAND);
                const string RIGHT_BRACKET = "}";
                scriptTextBuilder.AppendLine(RIGHT_BRACKET);

                string setContextKeyFunction = scriptTextBuilder.ToString();

                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, ORDER_OR_STOCK_NUMBER_SCRIPT_KEY, setContextKeyFunction,
                                                       true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now contextKey is properly set by Javascript and I can consume it's value in my GetOrderOrStockNumbers method.

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked and then i found out you can just set the context key in code behind under page load

```
ExtenderID.ContextKey = Control.SelectedValue;
```

And it works...